# SugarCRM: How can I allow a specific user to view only his/her leads and the leads of specific users?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

I'd like to set permission to allow a specific user to view only his/her leads and the leads of specific users. For example, user John can only view his leads and the leads assigned to Tom, Kate, Anne, and Robert.

I'm using SugarCRM Community Edition. Version 6.5.17.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a teams solution for SugarCRM Community Edition. This way you can put John, Tom, Kate, Anne, and Robert all on the same team. You likely want everyone but John to see only their own records so you would create a role with Owner permissions and assign that to the team. Then you would create a team role for John that grants permissions to see everything in John's team. SecuritySuite provides this exact functionality: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/securitysuite

Here is an example setup that is fairly typical of Community Edition installs with SecuritySuite: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/docs/securitysuite/example-of-a-typical-setup